# Setting up a church to house all personal funds

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

There are a few examples displaying how easy it is to set up a church ([John Oliver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Perpetual_Exemption)) that is exempt from taxation. Would it be beneficial and/or possible to set up one's own church to deposit all one's funds into and have the church "take care of one's necessities"?

Comment: How much will you set aside for attorneys' fees when the IRS disagrees with you?

Comment: To be clear,John Oliver did not use his “church” for personal gain. He took the donations that came in and donated them to Doctors Without Borders, which is a legitimate, legal thing for a non-profit organization to do. He closed the “church” after one month, avoiding any possible legal action.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If the IRS believes that your church is being run for your private gain, it'll lose its tax-exempt status.  And then you'll be liable for all the back taxes you didn't pay, plus fines and interest.  For example, there was a very long-running set of court cases on the [tax exempt status of Scientology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_status_of_Scientology_in_the_United_States).  If you tried to create a church that acted as a personal slush fund, the court battle would last much less time and you'd come out much worse for it.